# Clickable HTML5 banner with Flash Professional CC, including a clickTag

Tags: html, flash, button, clicktag

I'm using Flash Professional CC to create online banner. To be honest, I don't know anything about coding with HTML5. When I export my ActionScript into HTML5, all animations work perfect, but the button doesn't work. Can anybody tell me, how it's possible to make the whole banner clickable and how to integrate a clickTag?

Answer (score 0):

Create a  button symbol in your document. That gives you a cursor.

In your published HTML file add this in the head

var clickTag = "https://www.google.com";

On your canvas div right before the ending > add this

onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)"

Open in a browser, click and you will see it load google in a new tab.